# I am not sure whether this is a serious typos in a published article

Tags: formatting, review-articles

Just now i found few short form typos in my published articles few years ago.The mistakes is almost like this: If I declare my first sentences Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD) is one of the most important topics in high energy physics, but i state in same paragraph in second sentences and i type the short form QDC (wrongly) is a is the theory of the strong interaction between quarks and gluons......, i wonder is it consider serious typo? Thank you.

Comment: Which typos are theirs and which are yours?

Comment: Please structure your post more clearly. Mark the quoted sentences and check the others for typos/grammar.

Comment: Is this your article or one from someone else?

Comment: Actually is mine one, few years ago. If the mistakes are not so serious and it is in introduction. Do I need to write an email to tell editor?

Comment: In the future you might want to practice your writing skills with well articulated questions that respect the spelling rules of the English language. Just a thought...

Answer (score 6):

If readers or the editor have not complained to you - they probably smiled to themselves and continued reading - likely thinking "ha, done that typo myself"...

So, unless you have been contacted don't worry.

Comment: Bro, Thank for answering my question, i don't know why still can get errors even, me , my supervisor and colleague, each gone true twice about that article.

Comment: @KohPINWAI If the errors were in the data or the formulae then someone surely would have contacted you, as it is don't worry... I had a typo in the model I was doing in class today - made me annoyed - students found it funny for 10 seconds then it was done...

Answer (score 3):

Do I understand correctly that you're worried because you wrote QDC instead of QCD in one sentence?

Well, if this is the case, let me tell you clearly that *no one*, I mean, really, *no one* in their right mind would care about such a typo in a published paper, *at all*.

Comment: A student unfamiliar with the field would! I've seen plenty of typos and poorly-constructed sentences where an expert grasps what is meant instantly, while the novice is completely confused.

Comment: yes, this is the case, thank for answering my question.

Comment: @Allure A student unfamiliar with the field _could_, not would.But in such a case, the advisor can guide the confused student.

Answer (score 3):

Relax, you wouldn't be the first to make that typo. [Here's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5606) an example of a paper where that typo is made already in the first line of *the abstract*.

Unless you've defined both QCD and QDC abbreviations for closely related concepts, writing one instead of the other wouldn't be confusing for your readers. In general, clear typos do not pose any real issues. It's the subtle ones that change meanings or introduce errors that can be problematic.

Comment: i see, thank for the examples that provided.

Answer (score 0):

It says more about the proofreaders than you: if I see a typo in a published paper that's who I normally think of. Typographical errors in drafts can be exceptionally common, in final versions, a lot less so, and in submissions ideally non-existent. It is one of the proofreaders' jobs to make sure they don't exist at all and to make the paper as good as it can be to represent the journal and its cause.